# running query on Trino from airflow on docker env

Tags: python, docker-compose, airflow, trino

I'm trying to build really simple DAG just as POC, that reads something dumb from Trino table.
This is my docker-compose file, taken from airflow docs + what i added to have Trino as well:

```
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.8.1}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session'
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    # Use simple http server on scheduler for health checks
    # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/check-health.html#scheduler-health-check-server
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    # WARNING: Use _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS option ONLY for a quick checks
    # for other purpose (development, test and especially production usage) build/extend Airflow image.
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config:/opt/airflow/config
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8974/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      # yamllint disable rule:line-length
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.providers.celery.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}" || celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  trino:
    image: trinodb/trino
    environment:
      - QUERY_MAX_MEMORY=1GB
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8081/v1/status"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

The services seems all to work, i see my other DAGs in the UI.
Not directly relevant, but this is the query i want to run, and it's working from inside the trino container:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tpch.sf1.nation
```

The issue is with the imports of the DAG.
This is the script of the DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.trino.transfers.sql_check import TrinoSQLValueCheckOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.trino.operators.check import TrinoCheckOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2024, 2, 13),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'trino_example',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple DAG to execute Trino queries',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

start_task = DummyOperator(task_id='start', dag=dag)

# Assume you have a Trino connection named 'trino_default' in your Airflow configuration
trino_conn_id = 'trino_default'

# Execute the SQL query and store the result in XCom
query_task = TrinoSQLValueCheckOperator(
    task_id='execute_query',
    sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tpch.sf1.nation",
    conn_id=trino_conn_id,
    dag=dag,
)

# Print the result
def print_result(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    result = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='execute_query')
    print(f"Query Result: {result}")

print_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_result',
    python_callable=print_result,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

end_task = DummyOperator(task_id='end', dag=dag)

start_task >> query_task >> print_task >> end_task
```

and this is the error i'm getting inside the ui:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/example_trino_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/example_trino_dag.py", line 4, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.trino.transfers.sql_check import TrinoSQLValueCheckOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.trino.transfers.sql_check'
```

chatGPT and copilot suggested things such as

```
docker-compose exec airflow-webserver pip install apache-airflow-providers-trino
docker-compose exec airflow-scheduler pip install apache-airflow-providers-trino
docker-compose exec airflow-worker pip install apache-airflow-providers-trino
```

and

```
from airflow.providers.trino.transfers.sql_check import TrinoSQLValueCheckOperator
```

and more stuff like that around the imports, where the weirdest was:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

try:
    # Try importing the Trino operators with the new-style import
    from airflow.providers.trino.transfers.sql_check import TrinoSQLValueCheckOperator
except ImportError:
    # Fallback to the old-style import if the new-style is not available
    from airflow.operators.trino_check_operator import TrinoCheckOperator as TrinoSQLValueCheckOperator

try:
    # Try importing the Trino operators with the new-style import
    from airflow.providers.trino.operators.check import TrinoCheckOperator
except ImportError:
    # Fallback to the old-style import if the new-style is not available
    from airflow.operators.trino_check_operator import TrinoCheckOperator
```

but errors of import and missing module still exists.

All i want in the end, is to have the ability to run the most basic query on Trino, and save it to xcom. It's just for learning purposes.

Any help in understanding what i'm missing here.
I couldn't find related topic here.